# How to insert a 'Score Tracker' into a game being developed on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, game-center

I wish to track the amount of money 'In the bank' for my stock market challenge game.
I have yet to find a method of doing so? Any useful tips, links or advice would be appreciated. Needs to be able to display on all screens and adjust when the user buys or sells shares.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Xcode is a game engine now? Please read tag descriptions before posting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something to store information across multiple screens, I think the way to go is a Singleton class.  That seems to be the preferred way to deal with global variables in objective-c.  There is a pretty good tutorial [here](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/).  He goes into quite a bit of detail and has lots of code examples.  A quick Google search for "Singleton Objective-C" will turn up a bunch of others.